# How to check whether Microsoft Teams is using GPU accelleration?

Tags: 20.04, microsoft-teams

I am using Microsoft Teams and have the option to use GPU acceleration set to on.

Still it shows warnings when trying to give remote control in a call, that Hardware accelation is off.

How can I debug this?

Comment: I have the same problem.